# how to give ip address in simplewebsocketserver in python

Tags: python, websocket, webserver, chatterbot

When I'm running `var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");` the application is working but when I specify an IP address i.e., `("ws://192.168.3.63:9000")` & `(ws://HOSTNAME:9000)` as well there is no response.

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket
from chatbot import get_response ,checkForHyperLinks, convertToHyperLink
import http.server
import socketserver

class ChatServer(WebSocket):

  def handleMessage(self):
      # echo message back to client
      message = self.data
      response = get_response(message)
      self.sendMessage(response)

  def handleConnected(self):
      print(self.address, 'connected')

  def handleClose(self):
      print(self.address, 'closed')

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Ip="192.168.3.63"
port = 9000


server = SimpleWebSocketServer('',port, ChatServer)
print(server)
server.serveforever()
print("listening",server.serveforever())
```

Comment: You are not using `Ip` anywhere.

Comment: @DirtyBit  . If I pass IP also in server  , unable to call

Comment: var ws= new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000")  given in HTML to call server.py